# cURL download with multiple ranges

Tags: curl

I'm trying to download a series of podcast episodes using cURL. I know how to use a range of numbers to download several files matching a pattern, but what I can't figure out is how to have multiple ranges within a single URL.

Example URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/01_episode_1.mp3
http://www.example.com/02_episode_2.mp3
http://www.example.com/03_episode_3.mp3
...
http://www.example.com/52_episode_52.mp3
```

If I use

```
curl -O http://www.example.com/[01-52]_episode_[1-52].mp3
```

I get files like this:

```
01_episode_1.mp3
01_episode_2.mp3
01_episode_3.mp3
...
01_episode_52.mp3
02_episode_1.mp3
02_episode_2.mp3
02_episode_3.mp3
...
02_episode_52.mp3
03_episode_1.mp3
03_episode_2.mp3
03_episode_3.mp3
...
03_episode_52.mp3
etc...
```

But most of them are obviously not going to be valid files.

How can I use cURL to grab the files I want? Or maybe I'm trying to use the wrong tool for the job?

This is on OS X 10.10.3 and whatever version of cURL is installed by default on that platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
for i in {1..52}; do curl -O `printf "http://www.example.com/%02d_episode_%d.mp3" $i $i`; done
```

Comment: Perfect! I figured a loop might be required by my command line knowledge just wasn't up to snuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

While a weaker solution to this particular case, it's fairly useful in similar issues: `curl` features range globbing. I stumbled upon this thread, so someone else might too.

```
curl http://www.example.com/[01-52]_episode_[1-52].mp3 -o "ep#1_#2.mp3"
find . type -f -empty -delete
```

Word of explanation:

- Uses `curl`'s range globbing feature
- Weaker than a loop here, since there are two **almost identical** ranges which actually are meant to be identical (and with exception of leading zeroes in first - are).
- Chose `-o` in favour of `-O` to use local name and show `#1 #2 ... #n` feature of saving the files while using range globbing in `curl`.
- You could just choose 2nd number with `-o "#2.mp3"` but this would overwrite the file! DLing `01ep1.mp3` and `02ep1.mp3` saves just `1.mp3`
- Testing on example.com will yield peculiar results since that page always replies with 200 and same page, just so you know, that's how IANA set it up.
- Feature docs: https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline-globbing.html
- `find` call is here since I don't know the range maximum
- This saves all the files: if the range is [1-10] and there are just pages 1 and 2, it will save empty files for 3-9 (both inclusive). Hence: `find . -empty -delete` which deletes empty files. Obviously, due to aforementioned issue with **example.com** website this won't work there.